# JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError'

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ocr

I am trying to add OCR Library to my project, but I found there was no arm64-v8a library(.SO) file, so I download the OCR JNI Code, compile by android-ndk-r10e . 
Then I add the library to my demo and run, error occurs:

```
03-08 11:21:11.110: D/SurfaceView(22005): checkSurfaceViewlLogProperty get invalid command
03-08 11:21:11.232: A/art(22005): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError' thrown in void com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.nativeClassInit():-2
03-08 11:21:11.232: A/art(22005): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]     in call to GetMethodID
03-08 11:21:11.232: A/art(22005): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]     from void com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.nativeClassInit()
03-08 11:21:11.232: A/art(22005): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
03-08 11:21:11.232: A/art(22005): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x74d11fb8 self=0x7fa1c9a000
03-08 11:21:11.232: A/art(22005): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   | sysTid=22005 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fa5dc3eb0
03-08 11:21:11.232: A/art(22005): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   | state=R schedstat=( 1008955538 228340763 1201 ) utm=87 stm=13 core=0 HZ=100
03-08 11:21:11.232: A/art(22005): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   | stack=0x7fcd5b3000-0x7fcd5b5000 stackSize=8MB
03-08 11:21:11.232: A/art(22005): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
03-08 11:21:11.232: A/art(22005): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.nativeClassInit(Native method)
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, I am running my app in Android 5.1 when this error occurs. My IDE is Android Studio 1.5.0.

Comment: Are you using ProGuard or some other obfuscator/minifier? If so, you'll have to make sure you don't obfuscate any names used by the native library.

Comment: Why not use that project as a precompiled [dependency](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage) instead?

Comment: @Michael No, ProGuard  and minifier were disabled.

Comment: @rmtheis where can I get precompiled dependency files?

Comment: @tony Android Studio will handle this for you when you follow the "Usage" instructions at the link I sent above. You need to add a line to your app's `build.gradle`.

Comment: @rmtheis Thank you very much, I can use libraries now.  Infact, I didn't change any code or gradle file, but I compiled it on another PC, problem solved.